# Lua: Read file relative to module

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a module for Luakit that takes a `.js` file and injects it in every page, so a simple wrapper/workaround in absence of any web extension support. My only problem is currently that I cannot seem to find out how to read a file without `require` (because it's not a `.lua`-file, I just want to read it as a string) from the directory my module is in. Apparently, lua doesn't look for it there. I don't want to specify an absolute path, because it really only depends on the location of my module.

```
...
 |- mymodule.lua
 \- mymodule.js
```

module.lua:

```
local f = assert(io.open("mymodule.js", "r"))
local jsbase = f:read("*all")
f:close()

-- ...
```

However, this results in

```
E [core/common/lualib]: Lua error: mymodule.js: No such file or directory
```

***[EDIT]*** What I need is basically a function to use as `io.open(findContainingDirPathOfCurrentModuleWithoutHardCoding()..'mymodule.js')`

***[EDIT]*** Luakit runs on Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddling with the attempts posted, I now arrived at this solution. It is not perfect, but works alright, and should work without issue if the module name is unique (especially when there are no other `.js` files in the directories from `package.path`):

```
-- get name of this module
local modulename = (function (m)
  t = {}
  for e in m do
    table.insert(t, e)
  end
  return t[#t]
end)(string.gmatch(..., "[^.]+"))

local f = nil

-- find the js file named like this module from any relevant paths
for i in string.gmatch(package.path, "[^;]+") do
  -- ignore all ?/init.lua etc.
  if string.find(i, "?.lua") then
    f = io.open(i:gsub("?.lua$", modulename..".js"), "r")
    if f ~= nil then
      -- found a match!
      break
    end
  end
end

assert(f)

local jsbase = f:read("*all")
f:close()

-- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried simple example which finds the `.js` files relative to the module, But I kept in the same directory as the module.

```
-- Structure
- init.lua
- mod
 |- mymodule.lua
 |- mymodule.js

 -- mymodule.lua
 local f = assert(io.open("mod/mymodule.js", "r"))
 local jsbase = f:read("*all")
 f:close()
 return jsbase

 -- mymodule.js
 str = "Test String"

 -- init.lua 
 local str = require "mod.mymodule"
 print(str) -- Test String
```

Comment: okay, but here you specify the path relative to `init.lua`, not relative to `mymodule.lua`. This is exactly what I don't want to do. The main file has already found the location of `mymodule.lua` (in this case required by `~/.config/luakit/userconf.lua`, which require call could be traced back through the luakit codebase until you end up at the initial program call) — I don't see any need to hard-code the path "again". It is adding undesired redundancy.

Comment: I see, If your package path is already set to your current module in `userconf.lua`, you could do a relative path `io.open(package.path..'mymodule.js', 'r')`

Comment: As far as I can judge, I guess not: `package.path` is `./?.lua;/usr/share/luajit-2.0.5/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/luakit/lib/?.lua;/usr/share/luakit/lib/?/init.lua;/home/USER/.config/luakit/?.lua;/home/USER/.config/luakit/?/init.lua;/etc/xdg/luakit/?.lua;/etc/xdg/luakit/?/init.lua`

Comment: In Lua, your path needs to be relative from caller. For instance, only `mod/mymodule.js` works.  You could use `myPath = (...):gsub('%.','/')` and build a relative path to `.js` file, your EDIT will need this

Answer (score 0):

This works in Lua 5.2 / 5.3 / 5.4

**mymodule.lua** :

```
local f = assert(io.open(({...})[2]:gsub("%.lua$", ".js"), "r"))
local jsbase = f:read("*all")
f:close()
```

Comment: I have Lua 5.3.5, I get an error `E [core/common/lualib]: Lua error: attempt to index a nil value` — `...` equals for me `"mymodule"`

Comment: Wait, it might be that my luakit only uses 5.1

Comment: @PeterNerlich - Lua 5.1 and LuaJIT are unable to determine path to module file.  Use wsha's solution.  Or traverse all directories listed in `package.path` and search for your file.